# How to create a link in a web application that will work even if it doesn't reside within wwwroot?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a web app that runs fine in Visual web developer. But when I publish it to IIS, a link as follows: `href="/Default.aspx"` doesn't work. The page's address is now: `http://localhost/ MyApp.net/Default.aspx` .

So I tried adding a tilde: `href="~/Default.aspx"` but the browser is looking for: `http://localhost/ MyApp.net/~/Default.aspx` .

This is important because I would actually like to publish to a folder instead of `wwwroot`, but would not like to hardcode the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include runat="server" to have it resolved from the root.

```
<a href="~/Default.aspx" id="myLink" runat="server">Link</a>
```

Comment: Great. That was quick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ResolveURL()` to output your link references.  .Net handles all the plumbing for you regardless of your app location.

```
<a href="<%= ResolveURL("~/Default.aspx")%>" id="theLink">Link</a>
```

More reading: [Control.ResolveUrl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Does the `<%=` mean that it would run as ASP.Net (C# in my case)?

Comment: That is correct.  It's specific to ASP.NET and enables you to output your link using c# from within your aspx.